# PHP explode() returns array inside an array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, function, explode

I have the following function:

```
function GetTagsOfUser(){
    require "include/connect.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE User='Chona'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $tagsOfUser[] = explode(';', $row['Tags']);
        }
        return $tagsOfUser;
    }
}
```

And when calling it and printing it

```
print_r($Recomend->GetTagsOfUser());
```

I get the following:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "Paises" [1]=> string(7) "Francia" [2]=> string(19) "Revolucion Francesa" [3]=> string(3) "ONU" } }
```

It appears as if there was an array inside my array containing the strings, i want to have a single array, please help.

Comment: It may be because of this line: `$tagsOfUser[] = explode(...)`
If you change this line to `return explode(...)`, you will have a single level array

Comment: $tagsOfUser[]  .. the [] creates it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $tagsOfUser[] is an array:

```
$tagsOfUser[] = explode(';', $row['Tags']);
```

And explode returns an array, the result is exactly what you are doing.

Remove the "[]" from the variable name and your problem will be solved.

Comment: *Remove the "[]" from the variable name and your problem will be solved.* - What happening on two rows?

Answer (score 1):

You set the result array from [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) into another array (`$tagsOfUser`):

```
$tagsOfUser[] = explode(';', $row['Tags']);
```

You can use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to solve this:

```
$tagsOfUser = array_merge($tagsOfUser, explode(';', $row['Tags']));
```

---

```
function GetTagsOfUser() {
    require "include/connect.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE User='Chona'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $tagsOfUser= [];

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $tagsOfUser = array_merge($tagsOfUser, explode(';', $row['Tags']));
        }

        return $tagsOfUser;
    }
}
```

---

**You just get / need one row (for a specific user)?**

In this case you don't need a `while` loop or the `$tagsOfUser` variable:

```
function GetTagsOfUser() {
    require "include/connect.php";

    $sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM users WHERE User = 'Chona'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        return explode(';', $row['Tags']);
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}
```